# SQL Create View with a new column to hold values from DateDiff

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL code to create a view called v_students and I want to use the DATEDIFF() function to find the difference between the current date and the registration_date and then place those values in a new column called DaysSinceRegistration. I am running into an issue where there is a syntax error on the DaysSinceRegistration column name. Any suggestions, not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
CREATE VIEW v_students AS
SELECT
    registration_date,
    student_id, 
    salutation, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    street_address, 
    zip, 
    phone, 
    employer,
    fullname,
    DATEDIFF(day, registration_date, CURDATE()) as 'DaysSinceRegistration' 
FROM
    student
```

Comment: `as DaysSinceRegistration`, or `as "DaysSinceRegistration"`. I.e. use double quotes for delimited identifiers. (Single quotes are for string literals.)

Comment: What database are you using?  PL/SQL does not support `DATEDIFF()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah that would make sense, I am using PL\SQL. What would be my other option? I am new to the SQL world

Comment: Your question is plain SQL (DDL) - not PL/SQL. PL/SQL means stored procedures or function. A view is no PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `DATEDIFF` isn't Oracle (while PL/SQL, tag you used, is).

Difference in **days** is get by simply subtracting two `DATE` datatype values. Round them to see a *nicer* value. So:

```
round(sysdate - registration_date) as dayssinceregistration
```